# Extending android:WindowTitle

Tags: android, styles, themes, customization

I wish to extend `android:WindowTitle`

But `parent="android:WindowTitle"` no longer works in newer SDKs. It's a private style

What is a good public replacement for `parent="android:WindowTitle"`?

I am getting lost reading this [thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/550fce9670530d9b/9b2b2aa389dce367?show_docid=9b2b2aa389dce367).

Any alernative way for using `<style name="CustomWindowTitle" parent="android:WindowTitle">` with out machine dependent hot fixes so that my code compiles for rest of the team?

Comment: What do you mean by 'machine dependent hot fixes'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can open android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-6\data\res\values\styles.xml and copypaste your style from there.

I can see in there something like

```
<style name="WindowTitle">
        <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.WindowTitle</item>
        <item name="android:shadowColor">#BB000000</item>
        <item name="android:shadowRadius">2.75</item>
</style>
```

So you can define the same or similar style in your code. Generally, `data/res` directory in android SDK contains many interesting resources.