# Change both text and background color in title bar (Android)?

Tags: android, styles, titlebar

I build an Android app and I am trying to change the title's bar background and text colour.

In AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@style/ThemeSelector"
>
```

In styles.xml:

```
<style name="ThemeSelector" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/WindowTitleBackground</item>
</style>

<style name="WindowTitleBackground">     
    <item name="android:background">@color/titlebackgroundcolor</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/titletextcolor</item>
</style>
```

Using this code, I am managing to change the background colour but not the text colour.

Can you explain why this code does not work?

Thank you

Comment: checkout this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20769315/how-to-change-actionmode-background-color-in-android may be its similar to your question

Answer (score 2):

```
<style name="ThemeSelector" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/WindowTitleBackground</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/CustomWindowTitle</item>
</style>

<style name="WindowTitleBackground">     
    <item name="android:background">@color/titlebackgroundcolor</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomWindowTitle" parent="WindowTitle">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/CustomWindowTitleText</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomWindowTitleText" parent="android:TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/titletextcolor</item>
</style>

<style name="WindowTitle">
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/CustomWindowTitleText</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#BB000000</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">2.75</item>
</style>
```

Comment: You have a typo: it is `android:titleTextStyle`. It still does not have any effect.

Comment: I updated for use with a WindowTitle. The previous code was for an ActionBar. Let me know if it's working now.

Comment: I get `Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:WindowTitle'.`

Comment: Looks like WindowTitle was made private in the newer SDKs. You can replace it with your own style: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8253057/extending-androidwindowtitle