# Error:(4, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowTitle'

Tags: android

I am new to android programming and this is something I can't resolve in my code.

Here is my code which I get when I right click on the error and then click on go to source.

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowTitle">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
</resources>
```

Comment: You may find this post helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8253057/extending-androidwindowtitle

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

There is no attribute called "windowTitle." Change `<item name="windowTitle">true</item>` to `<item name="windowNoTitle">false</item>`

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work either. Anymore suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<item name="android:windowNoTitle"> false </item>
```

instad of

```
<item name="windowNoTitle"> false </item>
```

where did you go wrong?

`name`=windowTitle   (*wrong*)

`name`=**android**:window**No**Title  (*correct*)

The system won't recognize `windowNoTitle` attribute unless you'll specify that it belongs to `android` class (internal class of Android system)

Comment: Please add explanations to your answer.

Comment: Try to explain why it's wrong not only where it's wrong. The goal is to help OP to understand and develop his skills.

Comment: Okay, did some addition. Kindly have a look.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution. Actually i was missing the .R package file in the Package section of my app. I copied the .R file from another project and pasted it in my package section. It worked for me.

Comment: Try performing `CleanBuild` or `RebuildProject`

Comment: you should actually not mess with R.java files as they are auto generated by Android studio and are related to your project as it contains all the ids defined in the project.

Comment: You are right @Dennis. I did as you asked me to do and the windownotitle was solved however i have another problem can you please review it in my profile!?
thanks.

Comment: Done
and I've provided an answer to your current question as well. Kindly review it and mark it as useful (if you think so), so as to help other users too.
Thanks